# Facebook comment,like and share using android

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hi i am using facebook integration in android..i want to share post , comment and like how to get comment id and how to integrate our android app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should find anything you need, for your first steps, at the developers page of facebook:

[Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

[Documents](https://developers.facebook.com/docs)